# BIM Model upload via DataManagement API fails

Tags: autodesk-bim360, autodesk-data-management

When I try to upload a revit file via data management api, I get to the last step as describe in the tutorial, the file is uploaded but the extract state is failed. Reason file format or version not supported.
When I download the file I’ve uploaded, it says it’s revit 2009. The original file is 2019 so someone the file is getting corrupted / changed.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to translate your Revit model to a particular format?

Is the model manifest showing that the Revit model is 2009?

Also, what APS tutorial were you following?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upload of the file was done wrong via Postman, it wasn’t using binary format.

Comment: When you reuploaded the file, did it work without any issues?

Comment: yes it uploaded no problem why?